# react-native flipper no devices found issue

Tags: react-native, flipper

I want set flipper for my react-native project,

but Flipper says me **NO DEVICES FOUND**.
I searched all of ways, but I can't fix it.

**I tried...**

1. set correct android SDK location, IDB binary location

- so Flipper Setup Doctor says me All good!

2. reinstall flipper

- it works same error

Do you know another way?
Thank you

[flipper console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDvZ.png)
[flipper Setup Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFnqx.png)

Comment: as I see you already using mac so you don't even need SDK installed, just make sure that inside your project >> ios >> Podfile >> use_flipper
uncomment use_flipper in your podfile then install the pods again, try to restart the flipper and try one more time

Comment: @Guku I tried your way,unfortunatly it doesn't work
Thanks your comment

Answer (score 1):

choco install openssl

use command in the powershell as admin